# Springboot WebSocket: Cors policy blocking ws request

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, websocket

I'm trying to build a chat application. When hosting on a VPS I'm having this error message from browser

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/samplews/info?t=1603709911491' from origin 'http://my-server-ip:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is my WebSocketConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/samplews").setAllowedOrigins("http://my-server-ip:8081").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

I also tried to add a WebMvcConfiguration, which doesn't change anything:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://my-server-ip:8081")
            .allowedMethods("GET");
}
```

I'm using springboot version 2.2.1.RELEASE and also tried with the latest release.

The client is an angular application which does nothing but this:

```
ngOnInit() {
const ws = new SockJS(this.webSocketEndPoint);
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
this.stompClient.connect({},  (frame) => {

  // TODO: Do something when connecting ws
  console.log(frame);
    });
}
```

Client and server are on two different docker containers, this is docker ps result:

```
f3aa46625fc4        chatapp             "java -jar /app.jar"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   chatapp

7aa6e8a885de        chatui              "catalina.sh run"      16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   chatui
```

It all works fine locally (even if I use docker or ng serve the client and start the springboot server app via IntelliJ)

I don't think I'm missing basic information, any ideas?

edit:

I've changed this

```
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
```

to this:

```
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
```

And now I'm getting this error:

> GET http://localhost:8080/samplews/info?t=1603798741148 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

edit:

I was using localhost as the URL target for opening the socket, I should use the server ip instead, solved

Comment: Are you using an IP or a Domain as your origin?

Comment: I'm using an IP, as suggested by "my-server-ip" string

Comment: You should try to use a domain instead of an IP

Comment: As suggested in the docs they are using a domain: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-allowed-origins

Comment: @Esotopo21 were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @MuhammadAbuBakr yes, look at the bottom line of the question. Problem was I was opening the socket on "localhost" , so I was using the wrong interface. Using 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces) or the server public IP I was able to solve this

Comment: @MuhammadAbuBakr here is my code, hope it helps
https://github.com/Esotopo21/ChatApplication